# Linux　CSVファイルに格納されている日付がYYMMDDHHMMSS形式であることを判定する

Tags: linux, shellscript

**input_date.csv**

```
20151123181100,20151123181101
20151123181102,20151123181103
20151123181104,20151123181105
```

上記のようなCSVファイルに記載されている日付文字列が`YYMMDDHHMMSS`形式の日付になっているかどうかを、カンマ区切りごとに調べるシェルスクリプトを作成したいと思っています。

ネット等を参照し、いくつか作ってみましたがうまくいかずハマっております。
自作したシェルスクリプトを下記に記載しております。別のアプローチの仕方等も含めて、お力添えよろしくお願いいたします。

↓自作没シェルスクリプト

```shell
#!/bin/sh
date_file=~/input_date.csv

##試しに1列目だけの日付文字列を取り出して比較してみる。
while read line; do
    colm1=`echo ${line} | cut -d "," -f 1`
    echo "${colm1}" 　##echoしてみると、ここまでは意図通り動いてくれてるようです。
        if [ "`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d ${colm1}`" == ${colm1} ]; then
            echo "${colm1} is ok"
        else
            echo "正しい日付形式ではありません。"
            exit 1
        fi
done < ${date_file}
```

実行結果としては、正しい日付形式（真）で比較していてもelseの処理に移ってしまいます。
colm1で渡している文字列が、`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`のフォーマットにうまく変換されていなさそうですが、そこでもはまっているため、もっとシンプルなやり方がないかと模索しています。
→別質問版で`[date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 日付]`の件で質問版を立てていましたが、この件の解決に至らずです・・・。

Comment: `$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d '20151123 19:00:01'`なら想定通りの動作をするようですから…などと回答してから[過去質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19123/linux-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89date-ymdhms-d-2015-%E6%97%A5%E4%BB%98%E3%81%AE%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%A7%E6%9C%AB%EF%BC%96%E6%A1%81%E3%81%AB%EF%BC%90%E3%81%8C%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B "Linux　コマンド[date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 2015 日付]の出力結果で末６桁に０が追加される… - スタック・オーバーフロー")見たらそっくりそのまま同じ事書いてありましたね…　
何がわからないのかより明確にしてもらえると回答つきやすいかと

Comment: `-d`はGNU dateの拡張コマンドですが、この形式`20151123190001`はパースできないみたいです。ちなみに`+`は出力の書式をセットするだけで、入力の形式を制御する方法はないようです。BSD/Mac OSXのdateコマンドであれば`date -jf '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' 20151123190001`で`
Mon Nov 23 19:00:01 PST 2015`となりますが、トピ主さんの環境では使えないでしょう。

Comment: コメント・ご回答ありがとうございます。

csvファイルの保存されている日付が14桁の文字列数字となっているので、単純に抽出するだけでは、'20151123 19:00:01'とできないところで躓いておりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dateを使うのであれば、@emasaka さんの言うとおり食える形に整形するのが一番じゃないかと:

```
#!/bin/sh
date_file=~/input_date.csv

##試しに1列目だけの日付文字列を取り出して比較してみる。
while read line; do
    colm1=`echo ${line} | cut -d "," -f 1`
    d=`echo ${colm1} | sed -E 's/(.{8})(..)(..)(..)/\1 \2:\3:\4/'`
    if ( date -d "$d" >/dev/null 2>&1 ); then
        echo "${colm1} is ok"
    else
        echo "正しい日付形式ではありません。"
        exit 1
    fi
done < ${date_file}
```

ここまでするぐらいならperl使った方が早いかも

```
$ <~/input_date.csv perl -MTime::Piece -F, -nalE 'localtime->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") && say "$_ is ok" for @F'
```

Answer (score 1):

元の文字列と比較している意図がわかりませんが、それが不要であれば、ifの条件部分に過去質問でのargusさんの回答がほぼそのまま入ります。

```
if date -d "$(echo $colm1 | sed -r 's/(.{8})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})/\1 \2:\3:\4/')" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

Comment: 比較している意図は書式と正しい日付かどうかの確認でしょう。たとえば2月30日は存在しないわけです。

Comment: 存在しない日付の場合、dateコマンドはエラーとして終了ステータス1を返します。そのため、上記の条件式で判別できるかと思います。

    $ date -d 20150230; echo $?
    date: invalid date '20150230'
    1

Comment: コメント・ご回答ありがとうございます。
比較している意図としては、14桁の文字列数字であることを確認するためです。例えば、
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d '20151123'
のように日付が14桁になっておらず、且つ、それが存在する日付であればこのdateコマンド事態は正しく行われていました。
このコマンドの出力結果を確認すると、全然意図していない日付にはなってしまいますが、dateコマンドは通ってしまっていました。
このようなことを確認していたので、
①csvファイルから文字列を取得し、
②date +%Y~%S -d で、抽出した文字列をフォーマット変換し、存在している日付かどうかも確認し、
③フォーマット変換できていて存在する日付だとしても、csvファイルから取ってきた文字列が14桁だったかどうかを、比較して確かめる

ということをしたかったため、比較を行っておりました。